# Ng-repeat for nested object without nested ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

i created following plunker for my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/dkpFKU

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="t.thickness for t in products[0].wood"></select>
<div ng-repeat="product in products[0].wood |filter:{'thickness': selected.thickness}" >
    <ul>
        <li  ng-repeat="tex3 in product.textures">
        <h6 class="center"> <small>{{tex3.texture}}</small> </h6>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div> 
$scope.products = [
{
    "cat": "Product Category",
    "subcat_id": 1,
    "cat_id": 1,
    "ime": "Product Name",
    "wood": [
                {
                    "thickness": 10,
                    "value": 6.69,
                    "textures" : [{"texture" : "texture100"}]
                },
                {
                    "thickness": 12,
                    "value": 8.19,
                    "textures" : [{"texture" : "texture100"}]
                },
                {
                    "thickness": 16,
                    "value": 8.99,
                    "textures" : [{"texture" : "texture100"}]
                },
                {
                    "thickness": 16,
                    "value": 9.99,
                    "textures" : [{"texture" : "texture200"}]
                },
                           {
                    "thickness": 16,
                    "value": 9.99,
                    "textures" : [{"texture" : "texture300"}]
                },
                {
                    "thickness": 25,
                    "value": 14.29,
                    "textures" : [{"texture" : "texture100"}]
                },
                {
                    "thickness": 28,
                    "value": 16.29,
                    "textures" : [{"texture" : "texture100"}]
                }
            ]
},

]
```

The idea is to sort different wood on their thickness and then generate all the textures from .json file that fit that thickness (so that user can select texture in next step). My problem is the usage of nested ng-repeat - since this prevents me from generating textures as class="large-block-grid-12" (i'm using foundation). Is there any other way to generate the textures of selected thicknes?? Should i maybe change the json structure ?

I'm complete begginer in Angular and in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think you need to make one small change to your data structure and then I adjusted your HTML a little I am able to use a custom class on texture.  I hope this helps.  Here is the [Plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/SJiiU6IvV5bje09Abkex?p=preview)

HTML

```
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.25"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

   <label>Thickness
            <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="t.thickness for t in test.wood"></select>
      </label>
```

```
    <span ng-repeat="t in test.wood | filter:selected.thickness">
                 {{t.textures}}
       </span>
  </div>



  </body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.test ={
    "cat": "Product Category",
        "subcat_id": 1,
        "cat_id": 1,
        "ime": "Product Name",
        "wood": [
                {
                    "thickness": 10,
                    "value": 6.69,
                    "textures" : "texture100"
                },
                {
                    "thickness": 12,
                    "value": 8.19,
                    "textures" : "texture100"
                },
                {
                    "thickness": 16,
                    "value": 8.99,
                    "textures" : "texture100"
                },
                {
                    "thickness": 16,
                    "value": 9.99,
                    "textures" : "texture200"
                },
                           {
                    "thickness": 16,
                    "value": 9.99,
                    "textures" : "texture300"
                },
                {
                    "thickness": 25,
                    "value": 14.29,
                    "textures" : "texture100"
                },
                {
                    "thickness": 28,
                    "value": 16.29,
                    "textures" : "texture100"
                }
            ]
  };

});
```

Comment: Main reason why I wanted to avoid nesting ng-repeat is because i want list to output data in horizontal fashion. These textures will actually be images stacked horizontally like a gallery for example. Your solution uses a div ng-repeat as parent that again results in each li item going to its own line - unless i'm missing something in css ? Also is it valid to use <li> without <ul> - like in your code ?

Comment: the <li> might not be the proper way to do it but it gets the job done for a template.  Also I guess your question wasnt that clear you said you couldnt use the class.  let me see what I can figure out with horizontal ng-repeat

Comment: I updated my answer with your textures going horizontal.  I had to change your data and code a little.

Comment: Awesome, this solves the issue. Yes now that i review my initial question maybe i was unclear (i wanted to point out the large-block-grid class from foundation), thank you for the help. Maybe just to add to your solution - in my code i'm using | unique filter on thickness dropdown so that the same thickness value isn't repeating. Unique filter is part of: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/