# Nested json ng-repeat not working

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to access the value 1 like so.

```
var m = {
    {"name":"name"},
    {"contents":[{'one':1,'two':2}]}
};

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = m;
    $scope.contents = m.contents;
}

{{contents.one}}
{{items.contents.one}}
<li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.one}}{{item.two}}</li>
```

None of them works. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m` is an array and arrays don't have object properties.

The property `contents` exists in the second element of the array.

Try:

```
$scope.contents = m[1].contents;
```

It would seem that the preffered structure you would want would be an object not array:

```
var m = {
    "name":"name",
    "contents":[{'one':1},{'two':2}]
};
```

Comment: Is there any way I can access the element without index? I mean, with specific key?

Comment: Also your contents array should use the same property names in each object

Comment: I am sorry that I wrote '[' instead of '{'. I intended to talk about a json object that has an array inside. How do you do it if it is an object?

Comment: how do you do what? Changing the outer braces you just created an invalid object

Comment: I mean if I have a json object that has an array inside, how do I access the array item with property name? If I have a json object {name:'name',contents:[{'one":1},{'two":2}], how do I access 'one'?

Comment: do you control the source? Having different property names in each object of array is not common

Comment: You are right. I wrote the wrong description. It should be {name:'name',contents:[{'one":1, 'two":2}]}. If so, how can I get to the property 'one'?

Comment: How can I achieve that with angular template?

Comment: `{{item[0].one}} {{item[1].two}}`  ... again, do you control the data source? WOuld be a lot simpler to have consistent structure of objects

Comment: I mean.. with ng-repeat.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532207/ng-repeat-for-nested-object-without-nested-ng-repeat  In the data structure like this, you get array inside a json object.

Comment: sure...and as I keep saying the property names are consistent in the objects in that data. Yours are not and you haven't answered why

Comment: The above is just a sample data that I made to ask a question. It has nothing to do with real data that has relevant property names. I can have something like {name:'name',contents:[{'address':1, 'phone':2},{'address':1, 'phone':2}]}. How do you get {'address':x,'phone':y} repeatedly using ng-repeat?

Comment: ok...and that horrible example with different property names and invalid syntax in each object made for a lot of wasted time to sort this out. Look at example in docs or in tutorial in docs site how to do it.... or any `ng-repeat` example anyhwre on the web

Comment: I know I made mistakes in writing the example. I am sorry for wasting your time. But I am asking this question because I could not figure this out using tutorial. Tutorials do have ng-repeat to loop through json object, but they don't teach me about nested json object. Could you help me out?

Comment: create a demo with some legitimate usable data

Comment: what if the data is the link above I suggested? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532207/ng-repeat-for-nested-object-without-nested-ng-repeat I want to use ng-repeat to get thickness, value and structure of wood. Unlike the answer in the link, <span ng-repeat="t in test.wood>{{t.textures}}</span> does not work for me.

Comment: Use [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) to start a demo , even if it's not working .... but at least with some representative data

Comment: Just created it using the data linked above. http://plnkr.co/edit/Qy1qJ6FeKQMOYD0lSlCx?p=preview

Comment: works fine when you fix path to your script  http://plnkr.co/edit/6bxhSt5X3e1fAx4YGUFI?p=preview

Comment: For some reason, it's not working on my machine.. At least I got a working example. Thank you, Charlie. I do appreciate your time.